# Starting an activity from another package

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, package, manifest

I'm trying to start an activity from another package withing the same project. The problem is that I keep geet errors saying that it can't find the class and asks me if I declared it in my  manifest file. Here is the Manifest file for the project, the code for the class and the log which states the exception given. The two source packeges are simply named "ingegneria" and "unisannioportal" or just consider them "package1" and "package2".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="unisannioportal.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="ingegneria.ElencoAvvisiActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_elenco_avvisi" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="ingegneria.AvvisoActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_avviso" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

here is the code for the main class:

```
package unisannioportal;



import com.example.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
private String titolo;
private String[] dipartimenti;

private DrawerLayout menuDrawerLayout;
private ListView elencoMenuListView;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle menuDrawerToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    titolo = this.getTitle().toString();
    dipartimenti = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.departments_array);
    menuDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    elencoMenuListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    elencoMenuListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, dipartimenti));


    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
    elencoMenuListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, dipartimenti));


    elencoMenuListView.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());


    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);


    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
    menuDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                  /* host Activity */
            menuDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
            ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(titolo);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(titolo);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
    menuDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(menuDrawerToggle);

   if (savedInstanceState == null) 
   {
        selectItem(0);
    }
}




/*@Override*/
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
     if (menuDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


/* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener 
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
    {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}



private void selectItem(int position) 
{

    if(position == 0)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ingegneria.ElencoAvvisiActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }
  /*  // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

    // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);*/
}
```

Comment: Post the logcat please.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try something like this:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            PackageManager manager = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
            intent = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(YourPackageName);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);    
            startActivity();
```

Answer (score 0):

the package declaration has no error.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
```

But the error locates in the activity declaration.

```
<activity
    android:name="ingegneria.ElencoAvvisiActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_elenco_avvisi" >
</activity>
```

because there is *one dot missing* before the activity name. should look like below:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ingegneria.ElencoAvvisiActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_elenco_avvisi" >
</activity>
```

or

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.ingegneria.ElencoAvvisiActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_elenco_avvisi" >
</activity>
```